# Request Dropdown list

Tags: php, dropdown

I have a dropdown list with 5 elements (Volleyball, Handball, Rugby, Basketball, Autres)
I wish for example to select the element "Rugby" in my form, then confirm.

My problem is when I wish to change my old choice in my form (edit); the element "Rugby" is not the element which has been save previously.
By default I always have the element "VolleyBall".

```
[![<td>Type de Club:</td><td>
                <select name="type_club" style="width:144px">
                    <option>Volley-Ball</option>
                    <option>Hand-Ball</option>
                    <option>Rugby</option>
                    <option>Basket-Ball</option>
                    <option>Autres</option>
                </select>][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xQ83B.png
```

Here is my code.

```
<?php
// including the database connection file
include_once("config_bd.php");

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{   

    $pk_club = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['pk_club']);

    $nom_club = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['nom_club']);
    $type_club = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['type_club']);   

    // checking empty fields
    if(empty($nom_club) || empty($type_club)) { 

        if(empty($nom_club)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Le nom du club est vide.</font><br/>";
        }

        if(empty($type_club)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Le type du club est vide.</font><br/>";
        }       
    } else {    
        //updating the table
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE clubs SET nom_club='$nom_club',type_club='$type_club' WHERE pk_club=$pk_club");

        //redirectig to the display page. In our case, it is index.php
        header("Location: vue_club.php");
    }
}


//getting id from url
$pk_club = $_GET['pk_club'];

//selecting data associated with this particular id
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM clubs WHERE pk_club=$pk_club");

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $nom_club = $res['nom_club'];
    $type_club = $res['type_club'];
}
?>
<html>
<head>  

</head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Palais des Sports</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style1.css">
<body>  

    <div class="bandeau-bleu">
    <h2>Palais des Sports</h2>
    <a href="index.php?logout='1'"><i class="material-icons">&#xe897;</i></a>
    <a href="welcome.php"><i class="material-icons">&#xE88A;</i></a>
    </div>

    <div class="form_encodage">
        <a href="vue_club.php"><h3>Cliquez ici pour afficher les enregistrements</h3></a>
    <br />
        <h4> Editer un enregistrement</h4><br />

    <form name="form1" method="post" action="edit_club.php">
        <table border="0">
            <tr> 
                <td>Nom du Club:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="nom_club" value="<?php echo $nom_club;?>"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr> 
                <td>Type de Club:</td><td>
            <select name="type_club" style="width:144px">
                <option>Volley-Ball</option>
                <option>Hand-Ball</option>
                <option>Rugby</option>
                <option>Basket-Ball</option>
                <option>Autres</option>
            </select>
        </td></tr>

                <td><input type="submit" name="update" class="bouton_bleu" value="Update"></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="pk_club" value=<?php echo $_GET['pk_club'];?>></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `selected` property with `options`.

Below is updated code for dropdown you have put thin `td`.

**Try this:**

```
<td>Type de Club:</td><td>
            <select name="type_club" style="width:144px">
                <option <?php if(isset($type_club) and $type_club=='Volley-Ball'){ echo 'selected'; }?>>Volley-Ball</option>
                <option <?php if(isset($type_club) and $type_club=='Hand-Ball'){ echo 'selected'; }?>>Hand-Ball</option>
                <option <?php if(isset($type_club) and $type_club=='Rugby'){ echo 'selected'; }?>>Rugby</option>
                <option <?php if(isset($type_club) and $type_club=='Basket-Ball'){ echo 'selected'; }?>>Basket-Ball</option>
                <option <?php if(isset($type_club) and $type_club=='Autres'){ echo 'selected'; }?>>Autres</option>
            </select>
        </td>
```

**Complete updated code:**

```
<?php
// including the database connection file
include_once("config_bd.php");

if(isset($_POST['update']))
{   

    $pk_club = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['pk_club']);

    $nom_club = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['nom_club']);
    $type_club = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $_POST['type_club']);   

    // checking empty fields
    if(empty($nom_club) || empty($type_club)) { 

        if(empty($nom_club)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Le nom du club est vide.</font><br/>";
        }

        if(empty($type_club)) {
            echo "<font color='red'>Le type du club est vide.</font><br/>";
        }       
    } else {    
        //updating the table
        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "UPDATE clubs SET nom_club='$nom_club',type_club='$type_club' WHERE pk_club=$pk_club");

        //redirectig to the display page. In our case, it is index.php
        header("Location: vue_club.php");
    }
}


//getting id from url
$pk_club = $_GET['pk_club'];

//selecting data associated with this particular id
$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM clubs WHERE pk_club=$pk_club");

while($res = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
    $nom_club = $res['nom_club'];
    $type_club = $res['type_club'];
}
?>
<html>
<head>  

</head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Palais des Sports</title>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style1.css">
<body>  

    <div class="bandeau-bleu">
    <h2>Palais des Sports</h2>
    <a href="index.php?logout='1'"><i class="material-icons">&#xe897;</i></a>
    <a href="welcome.php"><i class="material-icons">&#xE88A;</i></a>
    </div>

    <div class="form_encodage">
        <a href="vue_club.php"><h3>Cliquez ici pour afficher les enregistrements</h3></a>
    <br />
        <h4> Editer un enregistrement</h4><br />

    <form name="form1" method="post" action="edit_club.php">
        <table border="0">
            <tr> 
                <td>Nom du Club:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="nom_club" value="<?php echo $nom_club;?>"></td>
            </tr>

            <tr> 
                <td>Type de Club:</td><td>
            <select name="type_club" style="width:144px">
                <option <?php if(isset($type_club) and $type_club=='Volley-Ball'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>Volley-Ball</option>
                <option <?php if(isset($type_club) and $type_club=='Hand-Ball'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>Hand-Ball</option>
                <option <?php if(isset($type_club) and $type_club=='Rugby'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>Rugby</option>
                <option <?php if(isset($type_club) and $type_club=='Basket-Ball'){ echo 'selected'; } ?>>Basket-Ball</option>
                <option <?php if(isset($type_club) and $type_club=='Autres'){ echo 'selected'; }?>>Autres</option>
            </select>
        </td></tr>

                <td><input type="submit" name="update" class="bouton_bleu" value="Update"></td>
                <td><input type="hidden" name="pk_club" value=<?php echo $_GET['pk_club'];?>></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to query your database before loading your select form to get the previous save then build your list

```
$sqla= "SELECT * FROM `save_table` WHERE `id` = $id ";
$result = $conn->query($sqla);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
$save = $row['save'];
$select= ('<td>Type de Club:</td><td>
        <select name="type_club" style="width:144px">
            <option>');

$select.='$save';
$select.='</option> <option>Volley-Ball</option>
            <option>Hand-Ball</option>
            <option>Rugby</option>
            <option>Basket-Ball</option>
            <option>Autres</option>
        </select>';

echo $select;
```

You can also use if statements to remove the second $save variable from the list before you build it so there is no repeat option in the list.

Comment: @chester sell: thank you , my problem is resolve. ^^